# If curve $y^2 = 4ax$ and $y= e^{-\frac{x}{2a}}$ are orthogonal then what value of $a$ can be taken?

Tags: derivatives

If curve $y^2 = 4ax$ and $y= e^{-\frac{x}{2a}}$ are orthogonal then what value of $a$ can be taken?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

- If $y^2=4ax$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{2a}{y}$
- If $y=\exp(-x/2a)$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{y}{2a}$

Thus, if the two curves intersect, the product of their slopes at this point will be $\left( \dfrac{2a}{y} \right) \left( -\dfrac{y}{2a}\right)=-1$, so they cross at right angles, i.e. are orthogonal.

Note then that if $a>0$, the curves cross by the intermediate value theorem; at $x=0$, the exponential is higher, but for large $x$, the parabola will be higher. The curves will also exist for $a<0$, as this corresponds simply to reflect both curves in the $y$-axis.